# Robot Framework Test Flow

Tags: robotframework, testcase

It's possible to require an execution of a specific test case before the execution of the current test case?

My test cases are organized in several folder and it's possible that a test require the execution of the another test placed in the another folder (see the image below).

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good / recommended / possible way to go.

Robot framework doesn't support it, and for a good reason. It is not sustainable to create such dependencies in the long term (or even short term).

Tests shouldn't depend on other tests. Mainly not on other tests from a different suite. What if the other suite was not run?

You can work around the issue in two ways:

You can define a file called

```
__init__.robot
```

In a directory. That suite setup and suite teardown in the file would run before anything in the underlying folders.

You can also turn the other test into a keyword so:

Test C simply calls a keyword that makes Test C run and also updates a global variable (Test_C_already_runs)

Test B would use then issue

```
run if  '${Test_C_already_runs}'=='true'  Test_C_Keyword
```

You would have to set a value to Test_C_already_runs before that anyway (as part of variable import, or as part of some suite_setup) to prevent variable not found error.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do if the test cases are in different files, short of reorganizing your tests.

You can control the order that suites are run, and you can control the order of tests within a file, but you can't control the order of tests between files.

Best practices suggest that tests should be independent and not depend on other tests. In practice that can be difficult, but at the very least you should strive to make test suites independent of one another.